# Buffer around outline of polygon

Tags: qgis, buffer

I'm fairly new to QGIS, and I'm trying to create a buffer around the outline of Spain (including the coastline and boarders). When I do so, it buffers all the country from center to the edge, I just need the edge if that makes sense.

[image: the picture attached here shows the whole country, and I'd like to buffer the outline of it]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to join all the polygons in your map together,

So given (for example) the GB constituencies:

[image]

You run `dissolve` (in the vector geometry menu of the processing toolbox) to give a single (multi)polygon:

[image]

Then you can buffer it as you want.

Answer (score 5):

For dissolving polygons for buffer, you can just check `Dissolve result` option in `Buffer` parameters:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to do the following:

- Dissolve the detailed administrative boundaries based on a field in the attribute table that has same value
- The output of the dissolve will have only one boundary that covers whole Spain.
- Then you can use buffer to buffer the outline.
- If you need only the mainland without considering the islands, then select the mainland and apply buffer on the selected feature.