# Buffering around all borders of EEZ regions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, buffer, point-in-polygon, multi-polygon

I have a layer containing points (in yellow) and a layer containing the [Exclusive economic zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_economic_zone) of all countries (as polygons, its geometry is MultiPolygon). See the image below:

[image]

I would like to create a buffer around the edges of all EEZ regions and determine how many of the points are contained within the buffered region.

I tried finding relevant questions on this website, but haven't found one that answers mine yet. For instance, there's [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300959/buffer-around-outline-of-polygon), but it focuses on dissolving all separate polygons depicting the Spanish autonomous communities and creating a buffer around Spain as a whole. This is not what I'd like to do. I would like to create a buffer around the lines that trace out the borders of the separate communities, or in my case, the EEZ regions.

Is there a way to do that in QGIS 3.10.11?

I followed @Eric's answer, but I run into some difficulties. Here's the menu for the buffering of the polygons:

[image]

I see a <kbd>Modify All Features</kbd> button, but I don't want to modify anything, I just want to create a new layer with the buffer. What am I doing wrong?

Also, it seems that when I do this, it buffers inwards, and it only buffers the countries on the coastal area (not the EEZ themselves). Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: @Taras do you perhaps know why the buffering happens inwards on the mainland?

Comment: @Taras I would like the buffer extend outwards, away from the mainland and to the sea, instead of going inwards (i.e. making the land area larger instead of smaller)

Comment: @Taras that's it! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Convert your `polygons to lines`, then buffer the lines by the distance you are interested in. Beware that you might have to `reproject` the data, since buffering can't be done reliable using degree-based CRS. Then use `select by location` to determine which points lie within the created buffer.

Comment: Why convert to lines? You can directly buffer to polygons...

Comment: @Babel as far as I understood it, OP is interested in points close to the borders, not in all the points within a polygon and its buffer.

Comment: OK, but if you buffer the line, the buffer will be on both sides of the line (if you don't choose single sided buffers), thus within the polygon and outside. If you create a buffer around the polygon, you can use `difference` to substract the initial polygon from the buffer.

Comment: True enough @Babel. I guess OP needs to add some details to their question.

Comment: If you convert to lines, then remove the lines that are coastlines, the double-sided line buffering solution is correct as I understand the question.

Comment: @Erik thank you for your answer. It seems simple enough to apply it, but I'm having some difficulties. For one, I see a button "modify all features" instead of just "run". Do you know why this might be the case? Also, the buffer seems to make the polygons smaller instead of larger, which isn't what I'd like

Answer (score 0):

A negative buffer a.k.a. inward buffering should do the job.

As was mentioned in [this article](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/wiki/Specify_distance_buffers):

> For polygon layers, a negative value can be used to remove the outer
> part of the polygons (to buffer inward).