# Reprojecting a base layer in QGIS - error message

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, error

I'm currently performing an analysis in QGIS that involves calculating areas (see [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412536/comparing-buffer-area-and-total-eez-areas) question). In order to do so, I would like to work in an equal area projection, like `EPSG:6933`. I already set the project as a whole to this CRS in the Properties section.

Now, I'd like to convert all the relevant layers to this CRS. I'm starting off with the base layer - Esri Gray (light). When I do Export, Save as... and set it to `EPSG:6933` in the menu (and tick off 'create VRT'), something goes wrong. I get the follow error message when I try to save the layer in the new projection:

[image]

The output mode in the Save raster data as... menu was 'Raw data'.

**Questions**: how should I reproject the base (raster) layer correctly? And do I have to reproject all layers everytime, or is there a way to set the whole analysis in one layer setting?

Comment: Since you wont calculate areas for a WMS service, you simply can rely on QGIS' on the fly reprojection.

Comment: @Erik does that mean I don't have to manually reproject the base layer? And which layers do I have to manually reproject to the correct CRS, and which ones not?

Comment: You need to reproject the ones you want to analyse - as long as they aren't already in a viable CRS.

Comment: @Erik okay, but how do I reproject the base layer 'one the fly' ?

Comment: QGIS automatically overlays layers with different CRS to the spot, where they "belong"  - aka "on the fly reprojection".

Comment: @Erik Alright, but suppose I'd like to use the contours of the countries in the base map (especially with regards to their outline next to the sea/ocean) in my analysis, how do I get those in the correct format in the correct CRS in QGIS?

Comment: Download them from OSM and reproject, or digitize them using a fitting CRS.

Comment: The error message means that you are trying to create a raster which is less than a single pixel in dimension based on the extent and resolution settings you have put in. You must set your desired extent then adjust either the horizontal and vertical resolution or the column and row numbers to reasonable amount.

Comment: By the way, I also agree with what Erik is saying. My comment above is simply trying to explain the error message.